# How to use mobile detect api (useragentinfo.co)

Tags: php, mobile, user-agent, detect

i am getting too much information from api, i can't use this, I  want only "device_model" and "device_type" from  this result, and how i can do it? 
What i am getting this result:

> {"device_model":"Emulator","os_version":"7","browser":"Chrome","browser_version":"60","os":"Windows","device_type":"Desktop","useragent":"Mozilla/5.0
>   (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)
>   Chrome/61.0.3163.100
>   Safari/537.36","device_brand":"Unknown","is_bot":false}

Mobile detect api

```html
<?php
$useragent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
// get api token at https://useragentinfo.co/
$token = "#API_TOKEN";
$url = "https://useragentinfo.co/api/v1/device/";

$data = array('useragent' => $useragent);

$headers = array();
$headers[] = "Content-type: application/json";
$headers[] = "Authorization: Token " . $token;

$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));

$json_response = curl_exec($curl);

$status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

if ($status != 200 ) {
    die("Error: call to URL $url failed with status $status, response $json_response, curl_error " . curl_error($curl) . ", curl_errno " . curl_errno($curl));
}

curl_close($curl);

echo $json_response;

?>
```

Comment: You probably should not post your api access token on a public discussion board such as StackOverflow - someone might miss-use it. I recommend you change it.

Comment: thank you <3 api key is not correct i change it before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are getting a standard json response from the api, you can just [json_decode()](http://php.net/json_decode) it and use it like this:

```
<?php

// Do your curl request and get json_response here...

// Decode json response
$result = json_decode($json_response);

// All of the fields are then accessed like this:
// $result->device_model (for e.g.)

?>

<b>Device Model</b>: <?php echo $result->device_model ?>

<br>

<b>Device Type</b>: <?php echo $result->device_type ?>
etc...
```

---

If you prefer to work with array instead, you can do this:

```
// Decode json response
$result = json_decode($json_responsem true);

// Then use it like this:
// $result['device_model'] etc...
```